# Jquery validate not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, forms

I am a jquery noob and I am having an issue in this script that is causing IE7 to display none of the code. IE7 is kicking back an error with my brackets, but I'm not sure what the proper syntax is. Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

The example is here http://jsfiddle.net/SeasonEnds/k8g3k/.

Comment: Your jsFiddle is set for MooTools instead of jQuery.  You also forgot to put your HTML in the Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to remove the various "hanging commas" in your validation options. For example, this is an error:

```
    email: {
        email: "Please enter your email address.", // can't have this comma here...
    }
```

HTH.

Comment: Is it only the areas where I display a message or should I also remove the commas after my brackets, as well?

Comment: Anywhere you are closing a bracket and not adding another. Commas should only be separating the option array (which is what you are actually creating).

Comment: Now I see what a mess this really is. Removing the commas and blazing through the errors now. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, you may find this helpful: Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar @ http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18359